Connection problem between NextJS and AdonisJS (backend framework)
Here's a quick summary of my code infrastructure: NextJS is there for the frontend side and AdonisJS is there for the backend side.
When the user connects (to the dash) NextJS sends the form data to AdonisJS which will check the codes. If they are good it returns a Barrer token which will be assigned to the client then for each request on the Dashboard NextJS will send a request to AdonisJS with the token and return the response to the client.
Here is my problem, the user is logged out (either directly redirected to the login page or I have an error like Array missing as if /api/users had not returned anything (yet if I make a manual API request with the old token it works). Completely random. This can happen once in 10 minutes or once per minute. This is often when, for example, I return to the site tab (i.e. during a request to the middleware). This does not happen on a particular page and this bug has been plaguing me for several weeks (I should point out that the site is under development so it has never worked).
Here is the middleware: It verifies that the user has still a valid token by testing the /api/users page of NextJS which itself makes a request to AdonisJS to verify. If it finds a user it returns true.
// middleware.ts

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { DataLayerAccesAdmin, DataLayerAcces } from '@/lib/auth/dal'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

const publicRoutes = ['/auth/login', '/auth/signup', '/']
 
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(path)

  const isDashboardRoute = req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')
  const isAdminRoute = req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/admin')
 
  const cookie = cookies().get('auth_token')?.value
  const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;
 
  if ((isDashboardRoute || isAdminRoute) && !cookie) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth/login', req.nextUrl))
  } 

  if(cookie && isDashboardRoute && !(await DataLayerAcces(req))) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL + "/api/users/logout" || "http://localhost:3000/api/users/logout", { status: 307 });
  } 

  if(cookie && isAdminRoute && !(await DataLayerAccesAdmin(req))) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL + "/dashboard" || "http://localhost:3000/api/users/logout", { status: 307 });
  }
 
  if (
    isPublicRoute &&
    cookie &&
    !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', req.nextUrl))
  }
 
  return NextResponse.next()
}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
}

// lib/auth/dal.ts

export async function DataLayerAcces(request: Request): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const authCookie = cookieStore.get("auth_token") || null;
    const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;

    const res = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/users`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authCookie?.value}`,
      },
    });

    if (res.ok) {
      const data = await res.json();
      if(data.id) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erreur :", error);
    return false;
  }
}

Thank you for your attention to this
